# Not able to remove a class from an element using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-in-posts-pages/) to add JQuery to a specific page. I am trying to remove a span class.
Here is a part of the DOM

```
 <!--// Header \\-->

                    <div class="careerfy-subheader careerfy-subheader-with-bg"  style="background-image: url('http://www.sohodragontalent.com/wp-content/uploads/subheader-bg.jpg');">
      <span class="careerfy-banner-transparent"  style="background-color: rgba(246,248,250,0.81) !important;"></span>
```

I am trying to remove the class named "careerfy-banner-transparent" from the parent class "careerfy-subheader careerfy-subheader-with-bg"

This is the JQuery Code that I have written but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
jQuery(".careerfy-subheader careerfy-subheader-with-bg").removeClass("careerfy-banner-transparent");
```

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.careerfy-subheader careerfy-subheader-with-bg` is not a valid selector for the element you're trying to remove the class from.

Firstly, to select an element based on two classes you need this syntax:

```
jQuery('.careerfy-subheader.careerfy-subheader-with-bg')
```

Notice the `.` for each class, and that they are attached. This means 'select an element with both these classes'.

The second problem is that this isn't even the element you're trying to remove. The class is on a `span` element inside the selected element, so your selected element should be:

```
jQuery('.careerfy-subheader.careerfy-subheader-with-bg .careerfy-banner-transparent')
```

This selects the element with the class `careerfy-banner-transparent` *inside* an element with `careerfy-subheader` *and* `careerfy-subheader-with-bg` classes. Having both classes is unnecessary unless using only one of them will select another element that you don't want to select.

However it seems like you actually want to remove the *element*, not the class. `removeClass` will change:

```
<span class="careerfy-banner-transparent"  style="background-color: rgba(246,248,250,0.81) !important;"></span>
```

into:

```
<span style="background-color: rgba(246,248,250,0.81) !important;"></span>
```

So the `span` will still be there.

If you want to remove the element entirely you need to select the `span` element and use `remove()`, not `removeClass()`:

```
jQuery('.careerfy-subheader.careerfy-subheader-with-bg .careerfy-banner-transparent').remove();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer taking the time to give a detailed explanation! It was really helpful!